# How to find the mapping between the dm-? files and its corresponding LVM files from the running kernel

Tags: device-mapper

It seems that the mapping relationship between the dm-? files and its corresponding LVM files can only be statically gotten via the following configuration.
So is there any other way to directly find the mapping relationship from the current running kernel ？

```
# ls -l /dev/mapper
total 0
crw-rw---- 1 root root 10, 58 Apr  9  2021 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Nov 24 18:30 mpdsk1 -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Nov 24 18:30 mpdsk2 -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Apr  9  2021 vgdat1-lvoradata2 -> ../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Apr  9  2021 vgroot-lvapp -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Apr  9  2021 vgroot-lvhome -> ../dm-7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Apr  9  2021 vgroot-lvinstall -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Apr  9  2021 vgroot-lvoradata1 -> ../dm-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Apr  9  2021 vgroot-lvroot -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Apr  9  2021 vgroot-lvswap -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Apr  9  2021 vgroot-lvtmp -> ../dm-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Apr  9  2021 vgroot-lvusr -> ../dm-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Apr  9  2021 vgroot-lvvar -> ../dm-6
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name of the device mapper device from sysfs:

```
$ cat /sys/class/block/dm-1/dm/name
fedora-root
```

This works for all DM devices, not only LVM.

If you want it the other way around, resolving the `/dev/mapper/<name>` symlink is probably the best way to do it (everything in `/dev/mapper/` are just "user friendly" symlinks, the `/dev/dm-X` is the real block device).

Alternatively you can use `dmsetup` to get the block device name:

```
# dmsetup info fedora-root -C -o blkdevname --noheadings
dm-1
```

Comment: 1) The solution on the running kernel can only be done on the RHEL 6 above.
2) The other solution on the DM table can be done on all the RHEL versions.
So what is the solution on the lower/older version of sysfs with RHEL 5？

Comment: @"Vojtech Trefny"   It seems that the lower version of the sysfs within the RHEL 5.x did not have a sub-directory strucure, which named dm under its parent sub-directory dm-<n>.